# Can't catch Timeout error in Discord Bot (Python)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently working for my own discord bot (Rock paper scissors game)

```
async def rps(ctx) :
    comp = rpslist[random.randint(0,2)]
    yet = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.message.author}'s Rock Paper Scissors {comp} Game!", description="Click on a button to start! Respond in 15 seconds.", color=0xFFEA00)
    win = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.message.author} won!", description = f"I have chosen {comp}.", color = 0x17ff0f)
    out = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.message.author}, you didn't respond in time!", description = "Make sure to click faster next time!")
    lose = discord.Embed(title=f"A bot is better than you.", description = f"I have chosen {comp}.", color = 0xff0000)
    tie = discord.Embed(title=f"You have the same level of cleverness as this bot", description = f"I chose {comp}.")
    m = await ctx.send(
      embed = yet, 
      components = [Button(style=1, label = "Rock"), Button(style=3, label = "Paper"), Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Scissors")])
    def check(res):
        return ctx.message.author == res.user and res.channel == ctx.channel
    try:
        res = await client.wait_for("button_click", check=check, timeout=15)
        player = res.component.label
        if player == comp:
            await m.edit(embed=tie, components=[Button(label="Round ended", disabled=True)])
        elif player == "Rock" and comp == "Paper":
            await m.edit(embed=lose, components=[Button(label="Round ended", disabled=True)])
        elif player == "Rock" and comp == "Scissors":
            await m.edit(embed=win, components=[Button(label="Round ended", disabled=True)])
        elif player == "Paper" and comp == "Rock":
            await m.edit(embed=win, components=[Button(label="Round ended", disabled=True)])
        elif player == "Paper" and comp == "Scissors":
            await m.edit(embed=lose, components=[Button(label="Round ended", disabled=True)])
        elif player == "Scissors" and comp == "Rock":
            await m.edit(embed=lose, components=[Button(label="Round ended", disabled=True)])
        elif player == "Scissors" and comp == "Paper":
            await m.edit(embed=win, components=[Button(label="Round ended", disabled=True)])
   except TimeoutError:
    await m.edit(embed=out, components=[Button(label="Round ended", disabled=True)])
```

I have already tried to catch the Timeout error but apparently it does not. Is there something I need to add or to delete it?

Note: All the buttons work within that 15 seconds, but after the 15 seconds it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried `except asyncio.TimeoutError:`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I have already tried to catch the Timeout error but apparently it does not." Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough and show a complete traceback, copied and pasted from the `Traceback (most recent call last):` line to the end, formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

`TimeoutError` is of asyncio so to use timeout error u need to add `except asyncio.TimeoutError:`