# Discord.py Button Timeouts

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm new to the ui interface (buttons). This following code is a part of my discord bot

```
        button1 = Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji='⬅')
        button2 = Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji='➡')

        view = View()
        view.add_item(button1)
        view.add_item(button2)

        *some embed code*
        
        message = await ctx.send(embed=embedVar, view=view)
```

Here I want to add a timeout to both of my buttons and disable them after sometime, but I'm struggling a bit as there is no example on the docs (without using subclasses).  How can I do so?

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Do these help?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72312277/16136190, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69981695/discord-py-disable-button-freeze-button-in-embed, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69109817/cant-catch-timeout-error-in-discord-bot-python (see the code in the question) Also, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your

```py
view = View()
```

with

```py
view = View(timeout=10) #in seconds
```

It adds a timeout to all components in that View.

Reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=view#discord.ui.View.timeout